# Running the Tango API displays a warning dialog on the library

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-project-tango

I am developing AR application by Tango.
The device is ZenfoneAR (Android 7.0 Nougat).

I improved the sample project and developed an application.
However, when launching the application, the following warning message will be displayed.

**Dialog Message**

```
Detected problems with app native libraries(please consult log for detail):
libtango_client_api.so: unauthorized access to "libbinder.so"
libtango_client_api.so: unauthorized access to "libcutils.so"
libtango_client_api.so: unauthorized access to "libutils.so"
libtango_client_api.so: unauthorized access to "libgui.so"
libtango_client_api.so: unauthorized access to "libandroid_runtime.so"
libtango_client_api.so: unauthorized access to "libui.so"
```

**logcat**

```
W/linker: library "libbinder.so" ("/system/lib64/libbinder.so") needed or dlopened by "/data/data/com.google.tango/libfiles/default/libtango_client_api.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace" - the access is temporarily granted as a workaround for http://b/26394120, note that the access will be removed in future releases of Android.
W/linker: library "libcutils.so" ("/system/lib64/libcutils.so") needed or dlopened by "/data/data/com.google.tango/libfiles/default/libtango_client_api.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace" - the access is temporarily granted as a workaround for http://b/26394120, note that the access will be removed in future releases of Android.
W/linker: library "libutils.so" ("/system/lib64/libutils.so") needed or dlopened by "/data/data/com.google.tango/libfiles/default/libtango_client_api.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace" - the access is temporarily granted as a workaround for http://b/26394120, note that the access will be removed in future releases of Android.
W/linker: library "libgui.so" ("/system/lib64/libgui.so") needed or dlopened by "/data/data/com.google.tango/libfiles/default/libtango_client_api.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace" - the access is temporarily granted as a workaround for http://b/26394120, note that the access will be removed in future releases of Android.
W/linker: library "libandroid_runtime.so" ("/system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so") needed or dlopened by "/data/data/com.google.tango/libfiles/default/libtango_client_api.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace" - the access is temporarily granted as a workaround for http://b/26394120, note that the access will be removed in future releases of Android.
W/linker: library "libui.so" ("/system/lib64/libui.so") needed or dlopened by "/data/data/com.google.tango/libfiles/default/libtango_client_api.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace" - the access is temporarily granted as a workaround for http://b/26394120, note that the access will be removed in future releases of Android.
E/linker: library "libavenhancements.so" ("/system/vendor/lib64/libavenhancements.so") needed or dlopened by "/system/lib64/libmedia.so" is not accessible for the namespace: [name="classloader-namespace", ld_library_paths="", default_library_paths="/data/app/<package name>-2/lib/arm64:/system/fake-libs64:/data/app/<package name>-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a", permitted_paths="/data:/mnt/expand:/data/data/<package name>"]
```

I think that it is related to "NDK Apps Linking to Platform Libraries" of the following site.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk

According to this, "libtango_client_api.so" is "private platform library"?

Or is there a mistake in my configuration file?

I do not know how to fix it, so I can not improve it. How can I improve my warning? please help me.

**app/build.gradle**

```js
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<package name>"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    apply from: '../version.gradle'
    compile "com.google.tango:sdk-base:${release_version}"
    compile "com.google.tango:support-base:${release_version}"
    compile "com.google.tango:support-reconstruction:${release_version}"
    compile 'org.rajawali3d:rajawali:1.1.668@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
}
```

${release_version} = 1.54

**Project/build.gradle**

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="<package name>"
    android:versionCode="0"
    android:versionName="0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application

       ...about application...>

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.projecttango.libtango_device2"
            android:required="true" />

        <activity

            ...about activity...>

            ...

        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

By the way, the configuration file is almost same as the Tango sample project.

Comment: Where does `libtango_client_api.so` come from? This file is expected to be present in /system/lib (or maybe /system/lib64); you are not expected to put it into your APK (unlike `libtango_support_api.so` and other libraries that are packed into [tango_support_java_lib.aar](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/blob/master/TangoReleaseLibs/aar/tango_support_java_lib.aar).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but this error occurs only in debug mode not in release mode. 
So as a workaround run your application in release mode.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about what you mean and why this is the solution.  An example and explanation