# Tango API linking against private native libraries API24+

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-ndk, google-project-tango

Are there any solutions for this problem?

[Running the Tango API displays a warning dialog on the library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233025/running-the-tango-api-displays-a-warning-dialog-on-the-library/)

Our team has the same problem. The guide mentioned doesn't really help. Not "libtango_client_api.so" is private, as far as i did understand:

```
"libbinder.so"
"libcutils.so"
"libutils.so"
"libgui.so"
"libandroid_runtime.so"
"libui.so"
```

are the private platform libs we can still use in api version 24, but in 24+ they will not be accessible anymore. The warning also appears on the latest c-examples. There must be a solution for that, caused by the fact that there exists applications without any warnings like this (Rtabmap).

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Where does `libtango_client_api.so` come from? This file is expected to be present in /system/lib (or maybe /system/lib64); you are not expected to put it into your APK (unlike `libtango_support_api.so` and other libraries that are packed into [tango_support_java_lib.aar](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/blob/master/TangoReleaseLibs/aar/tango_support_java_lib.aar).

Comment: Thy for your response,  libtango_client_api.so as well as 
 libtango_support_api.so need to be copied (via gradle) to the apk, that are no system libraries. I am working with the NDK.

Comment: I am afraid you are wrong. See e.g. [March 27, 2015 release note](https://developers.google.com/tango/release-notes#unity_sdk_changes_15). Look for `libtango_client_api.so` in your system lib. If your device does not have this library there, you should look for platform fix.

Comment: Okay, you are right. This seems to be the correct way, so libtango_client_api.so is a system library, which i don't need to include explictly. But this has no impact on the dependency issue, as far as i understand, it has to do with dependencies from this libtango_client_api.so through the listed prebuilt libs above.

Comment: Do you still see the popup dialog when you use libtango_client_api.so from `/system/lib` ? It's OK to have system libraries depend on other system libraries, even on N.

Comment: Yep it uses the system/lib now and yeah the dialog still appears in debug mode. Like in the linked thread: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk it is warning in further api versions 24+ the access to those libs will be removed.

Comment: Maybe the dialog will disappear if your manifest shows target api 23?

Comment: Already tried to downgrade target api version even through versions lower then 22. I assume this is more related to the device android api version which is 24. I think for now the best 'workaround' is to build the app in release mode and we need to wait for a newer version of the tango api.

Comment: I am afraid this shows (lack of) commitment to Tango from ASUS side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you duplicated the question because you are unable to comment yet.  I have the same issue so I cannot respond on that thread either but I can give you a workaround which seems very poor but I don't have any other solution.

For each missing file you can include the prebuilt library as the Developer Site suggests:

> ...you should update your app to either include its own copy of those libraries or only use the public NDK APIs.

I added the following to the make file and put a copy of the files in the relevant folder:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE          := binder
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../jni/lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libbinder.so 
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE          := cutils
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../jni/lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcutils.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE          := utils
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../jni/lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libutils.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE          := android_runtime
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../jni/lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libandroid_runtime.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This does not seem like the correct way to do this and I suspect there will be many dependencies.  GDB log shows which symbols I cannot load which I will include below.  I did start going through one by one seeing which one logcat complained about next in the hope it won't need them all but that may be in vain.  I can't believe I have to add all of the following symbols:

```
/system/lib64/libcutils.so
/system/lib64/libutils.so
/system/lib64/liblog.so
/system/lib64/libbinder.so
/system/lib64/libnativeloader.so
/system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
/system/lib64/libwilhelm.so
/system/lib64/libc++.so
/system/lib64/libm.so
/system/lib64/libbacktrace.so
/system/lib64/libnativehelper.so
/system/lib64/libmemtrack.so
/system/lib64/libandroidfw.so
/system/lib64/libexpat.so
/system/lib64/libnetutils.so
/system/lib64/libui.so
/system/lib64/libgui.so
/system/lib64/libinput.so
/system/lib64/libinputflinger.so
/system/lib64/libcamera_client.so
/system/lib64/libcamera_metadata.so
/system/lib64/libskia.so
/system/lib64/libsqlite.so
/system/lib64/libEGL.so
/system/lib64/libGLESv1_CM.so
/system/lib64/libGLESv2.so
/system/lib64/libvulkan.so
/system/lib64/libETC1.so
/system/lib64/libhardware.so
/system/lib64/libhardware_legacy.so
/system/lib64/libselinux.so
/system/lib64/libsonivox.so
/system/lib64/libcrypto.so
/system/lib64/libssl.so
/system/lib64/libicuuc.so
/system/lib64/libicui18n.so
/system/lib64/libmedia.so
/system/lib64/libjpeg.so
/system/lib64/libusbhost.so
/system/lib64/libharfbuzz_ng.so
/system/lib64/libz.so
/system/lib64/libaudioutils.so
/system/lib64/libpdfium.so
/system/lib64/libimg_utils.so
/system/lib64/libnetd_client.so
/system/lib64/libradio.so
/system/lib64/libsoundtrigger.so
/system/lib64/libminikin.so
/system/lib64/libprocessgroup.so
/system/lib64/libnativebridge.so
/system/lib64/libradio_metadata.so
/system/lib64/libmemunreachable.so
/system/lib64/libhwui.so
/system/lib64/libregionalization.so
/system/lib64/libstagefright.so
/system/lib64/libstagefright_foundation.so
/system/lib64/libeffects.so
/system/lib64/libstagefright_http_support.so
/system/lib64/libbase.so
/system/lib64/libunwind.so
/system/lib64/libstdc++.so
/system/lib64/libsync.so
/system/lib64/libpng.so
/system/lib64/libft2.so
/system/lib64/libdng_sdk.so
/system/lib64/libpiex.so
/system/lib64/libwpa_client.so
/system/lib64/libpcre.so
/system/lib64/libpackagelistparser.so
/system/lib64/libnbaio.so
/system/lib64/libspeexresampler.so
/system/lib64/libprotobuf-cpp-lite.so
/system/lib64/libRS.so
/system/lib64/libRScpp.so
/system/lib64/libdrmframework.so
/system/lib64/libmediautils.so
/system/lib64/libopus.so
/system/lib64/libstagefright_omx.so
/system/lib64/libstagefright_yuv.so
/system/lib64/libvorbisidec.so
/system/lib64/libpowermanager.so
/system/lib64/libstagefright_enc_common.so
/system/lib64/libstagefright_avc_common.so
/system/lib64/liblzma.so
/system/lib64/libbinary_parse.so
/system/lib64/libimage_type_recognition.so
/system/lib64/libtiff_directory.so
/system/lib64/libRS_internal.so
/system/lib64/libbcinfo.so
/system/lib64/libLLVM.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libavenhancements.so
/system/lib64/libstagefright_httplive.so
/system/lib64/libmediaplayerservice.so
/system/lib64/libstagefright_wfd.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libExtendedExtractor.so
/system/lib64/libdashplayer.so
/system/lib64/libart.so
/system/lib64/libsigchain.so
/system/lib64/liblz4.so
/system/framework/arm64/boot.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-conscrypt.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-okhttp.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-core-junit.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-bouncycastle.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-ext.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-telephony-common.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-voip-common.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-ims-common.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-apache-xml.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-org.apache.http.legacy.boot.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-tcmiface.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-telephony-ext.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-WfdCommon.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-oem-services.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-qcom.fmradio.oat
/system/framework/arm64/boot-qcmediaplayer.oat
/system/lib64/libandroid.so
/system/lib64/libcamera2ndk.so
/system/lib64/libGLESv3.so
/system/lib64/libjnigraphics.so
/system/lib64/libmediandk.so
/system/lib64/libmediadrm.so
/system/lib64/libOpenMAXAL.so
/system/lib64/libOpenSLES.so
/system/lib64/libwebviewchromium_plat_support.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libOpenCL.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libgsl.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libCB.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libqti_performance.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libqti-perfd-client.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libtango_hal.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libLiftParser.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libadsprpc.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libtango_hardware.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libtango_surface_texture.so
/system/vendor/lib64/lib-ims-rcscmjni.so
/system/vendor/lib64/lib-imsrcscmclient.so
/system/vendor/lib64/lib-imsrcscm.so
/system/vendor/lib64/lib-imsdpl.so
/system/vendor/lib64/lib-imsqimf.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libdiag.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libqmiservices.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libdsi_netctrl.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libtime_genoff.so
/system/vendor/lib64/lib-imsxml.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libidl.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libqmi.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libqdi.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libnetmgr.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libdsutils.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libconfigdb.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libqmi_cci.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libqmi_common_so.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libqmi_client_qmux.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libqmi_client_helper.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libmdmdetect.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libxml.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libqmi_encdec.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libsmemlog.so
/system/vendor/lib64/lib-imsrcscmservice.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libcxsparse.so
/system/lib64/libart-compiler.so
/system/lib64/libvixl.so
/system/lib64/libjavacore.so
/system/lib64/libopenjdk.so
/system/lib64/libopenjdkjvm.so
/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8996.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libqti-at.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libqti-gt.so
/system/lib64/libxml2.so
/system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so
/system/lib64/libmtp.so
/system/lib64/libexif.so
/system/lib64/libstagefright_amrnb_common.so
/system/lib64/libextmedia_jni.so
/system/lib64/libjavacrypto.so
/system/lib64/libkeystore-engine.so
/system/lib64/libkeystore_binder.so
/system/lib64/libkeymaster_messages.so
/system/lib64/libsoftkeymasterdevice.so
/system/lib64/libkeymaster1.so
/system/vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libadreno_utils.so
/system/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
/system/vendor/lib64/libllvm-glnext.so
/system/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
/system/vendor/lib64/egl/eglSubDriverAndroid.so
/system/vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8996.so
/system/lib64/libmemalloc.so
/system/lib64/libqdMetaData.so
/system/lib64/libqdutils.so
/system/lib64/libqservice.so
/system/lib64/libcompiler_rt.so
/system/lib64/libwebviewchromium_loader.so
/data/app/com.sample.moreteapots-1/oat/arm64/base.odex
/system/framework/oat/arm64/QPerformance.odex
```

I will be watching the other thread you referred to which I have upvoted and hope that someone will give us a sensible solution.  It seems unlikely that API 24 has only messed up Tango developers.

I programmatically generated make file code from the log and my program has compiled and run.  The Tango config returns null but that is a new issue I suppose.  Here are the [prebuilt includes](https://github.com/BarrieSharp/Resources/wiki/Tango-Shared-Library-Makefile-includes). Just add the files to the source path.

Comment: Thy a lot! This 'workaround' works and i was able to pull the prebuilts via adb myself. I tried first to only integrate those prebuilts called in the warning message, but as i included them many other dependendies occured. The solution to copy all of those dependencies was not intuitive enough for me, i think we will have to wait for a proper integration of tango into AR-core anyway.

Comment: I found another workaround based on some response to an github issue i created, unexpected the warning dialog disappears when building the .apk in release mode (-> signed apk). But i think the problem itself still exists.