# library is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace"

Tags: java, android, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I want to import below libraries in my Android Studio Project these are placed in */system/lib64/ folder*.
**I am getting below error**

```
2020-01-06 13:23:31.358 5171-5171/org.strongswan.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.strongswan.android, PID: 5171
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib64/libstrongswan.so" needed or dlopened by "/system/lib64/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
        at org.strongswan.android.logic.CharonVpnService.<init>(CharonVpnService.java:730)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3740)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:238)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1803)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

**on the line *System.loadLibrary("strongswan")***

```
        System.loadLibrary("strongswan");

        if (MainActivity.USE_BYOD)
        {
            System.loadLibrary("tncif");
            System.loadLibrary("tnccs");
            System.loadLibrary("imcv");
        }

        System.loadLibrary("hydra");
        System.loadLibrary("charon");
        System.loadLibrary("ipsec");
        System.loadLibrary("androidbridge");
    }
```

Comment: can some one help me on it..??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52515309/libraries-not-accessible-for-classloader-namespace-when-loading-dl4j-model-us did you check this thread

Comment: @sashabeliy yes I have already checked these threads but unable to handle this error till now. I have also read docs of android developer from where i get that if targetVersionSDK is greater then or equal 24 then it will generate RunTimeError while for below then 24 this is working perfectly.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html

Answer (score 13):

From Nougat onwards, Android prevents the runtime linkage of private symbols from system libraries (see [this blogpost](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/improving-stability-with-private-cc.html) in Android Developers).
You have two options:

1. Include those libraries in your APK so that you don't need to look for them in `/system/lib/`; or
2. Modify your Android ROM so that those libraries are considered public. This can be done by adding those libraries to `/system/etc/public.libraries.txt`.

Comment: If you are super brave, you can read `libart.so` address out of `/proc/self/maps` and then look in `Ghidra` for where symbols would be relative to the address loaded in memory.

Answer (score 2):

I also meet this error.The situation I tested is like this.

I put the so file in the [libs/yourCpuModel(armeabi-v7a)/] directory will be this error.

I put the so file in the [src/jniLibs/youtCpuModel(armeabi-v7a)/] directory will be this error.

But I put the so file in the [src/main/jniLibs/yourCpuModel(armeabi-v7a)/] directory will not.

I don't know why.Maybe you can try it.